# Trying to store a fetch value in a variable to display as a list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, frontend

I'm fetching the top 5 nft collections by volume to display them as a table but when I map the data it displays nothing. When a click the "get" button everything disappears in the webpage. I'm trying to display a table contaning the top 5 collections from the json received

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


const GetTop5 = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  console.log(data);

  
  const getAPI = () => {

    const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};

    fetch(`https://www.nftscan.com/nftscan/getTopTrendingData?range=1d&volumeSort=desc`, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.assets);
        console.log(response);
        })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={getAPI}>get</button>
      {data.map(nft => {return(<div><ul><li>nft.id , nft.floor_price , nft.sales </li></ul></div>)})}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default GetTop5
```

This is the index.js file

```
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import InteractiveList from './components/Top5Collections';
import GetTop5 from './functions/gettop5';


 

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
      <InteractiveList/>
        <GetTop5/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the console.log(response)

```
    "msg": "Success",
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "nft_platform": "CryptoPunks",
            "nft_address": "0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb",
            "floor_price": 73,
            "average_price": 89.01,
            "total_value": 1424.16,
            "count": 16,
            "image": "https://logo.nftscan.com/logo/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb.png",
            "highest_price": 109,
            "total_supply": 10000,
            "market_cap": 946096,
            "holders": 3376,
            "volume7dList": [
                {
                    "volume": 3153.86,
                    "time": 1657320855301
                },
                {
                    "volume": 3051.48,
                    "time": 1657407256164
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1810.31,
                    "time": 1657493656186
                },
                {
                    "volume": 696.88,
                    "time": 1657580056205
                },
                {
                    "volume": 4243.94,
                    "time": 1657666456226
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1611.36,
                    "time": 1657752856322
                },
                {
                    "volume": 543.88,
                    "time": 1657839256342
                }
            ],
            "price7dList": [
                {
                    "price": 80.8682,
                    "time": 1657320855301
                },
                {
                    "price": 92.4691,
                    "time": 1657407256164
                },
                {
                    "price": 86.2052,
                    "time": 1657493656186
                },
                {
                    "price": 87.11,
                    "time": 1657580056205
                },
                {
                    "price": 223.3653,
                    "time": 1657666456226
                },
                {
                    "price": 94.7859,
                    "time": 1657752856322
                },
                {
                    "price": 90.6467,
                    "time": 1657839256342
                }
            ],
            "opensea_floor_price": 73,
            "authFlag": 0
        },
        {
            "nft_platform": "BoredApeYachtClub",
            "nft_address": "0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d",
            "floor_price": 94,
            "average_price": 122.2112,
            "total_value": 977.69,
            "count": 8,
            "image": "https://logo.nftscan.com/logo/0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d.png",
            "highest_price": 180.69,
            "total_supply": 10000,
            "market_cap": 1265391,
            "holders": 6446,
            "volume7dList": [
                {
                    "volume": 1875.2,
                    "time": 1657320857704
                },
                {
                    "volume": 2201.59,
                    "time": 1657407258063
                },
                {
                    "volume": 762,
                    "time": 1657493658327
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1124.8737,
                    "time": 1657580058344
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1384.8,
                    "time": 1657666458362
                },
                {
                    "volume": 996.3,
                    "time": 1657752858380
                },
                {
                    "volume": 381.69,
                    "time": 1657839258398
                }
            ],
            "price7dList": [
                {
                    "price": 170.4727,
                    "time": 1657320857704
                },
                {
                    "price": 104.8376,
                    "time": 1657407258063
                },
                {
                    "price": 108.8571,
                    "time": 1657493658327
                },
                {
                    "price": 112.4874,
                    "time": 1657580058344
                },
                {
                    "price": 125.8909,
                    "time": 1657666458362
                },
                {
                    "price": 110.7,
                    "time": 1657752858380
                },
                {
                    "price": 127.23,
                    "time": 1657839258398
                }
            ],
            "opensea_floor_price": 99,
            "authFlag": 0
        },
        {
            "nft_platform": "Squares and Triangles by Maksim Hapeyenka",
            "nft_address": "0xa7d8d9ef8d8ce8992df33d8b8cf4aebabd5bd270",
            "floor_price": 0.155,
            "average_price": 1.547,
            "total_value": 840.0019,
            "count": 543,
            "image": "https://logo.nftscan.com/logo/0xa7d8d9ef8d8ce8992df33d8b8cf4aebabd5bd270.png",
            "highest_price": 169.69,
            "total_supply": 183131,
            "market_cap": 221808.2672,
            "holders": 34011,
            "volume7dList": [
                {
                    "volume": 735.4112,
                    "time": 1657320859833
                },
                {
                    "volume": 634.525,
                    "time": 1657407259892
                },
                {
                    "volume": 686.473,
                    "time": 1657493659926
                },
                {
                    "volume": 436.4589,
                    "time": 1657580060431
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1109.52,
                    "time": 1657666460757
                },
                {
                    "volume": 1982.9054,
                    "time": 1657752861278
                },
                {
                    "volume": 395.6019,
                    "time": 1657839261385
                }
            ],
            "price7dList": [
                {
                    "price": 1.0752,
                    "time": 1657320859833
                },
                {
                    "price": 1.2491,
                    "time": 1657407259892
                },
                {
                    "price": 1.8065,
                    "time": 1657493659926
                },
                {
                    "price": 0.6563,
                    "time": 1657580060431
                },
                {
                    "price": 1.5627,
                    "time": 1657666460757
                },
                {
                    "price": 2.0677,
                    "time": 1657752861278
                },
                {
                    "price": 2.5038,
                    "time": 1657839261385
                }
            ],
            "opensea_floor_price": 0.155,
            "authFlag": 0
        },
        {
            "nft_platform": "Super Cool World V2",
            "nft_address": "0x670d4dd2e6badfbbd372d0d37e06cd2852754a04",
            "floor_price": 0.56,
            "average_price": 0.6584,
            "total_value": 556.9921,
            "count": 846,
            "image": "https://logo.nftscan.com/logo/0x670d4dd2e6badfbbd372d0d37e06cd2852754a04.png",
            "highest_price": 0.95,
            "total_supply": 5080,
            "market_cap": 3062.732,
            "holders": 3007,
            "volume7dList": [
                {
                    "volume": 0,
                    "time": 1657320887824
                },
                {
                    "volume": 0,
                    "time": 1657407288105
                },
                {
                    "volume": 0,
                    "time": 1657493688119
                },
                {
                    "volume": 0,
                    "time": 1657580088132
                },
                {
                    "volume": 155.7175,
                    "time": 1657666488329
                },
                {
                    "volume": 228.1399,
                    "time": 1657752888460
                },
                {
                    "volume": 469.3439,
                    "time": 1657839288486
                }
            ],
            "price7dList": [
                {
                    "price": 0,
                    "time": 1657320887824
                },
                {
                    "price": 0,
                    "time": 1657407288105
                },
                {
                    "price": 0,
                    "time": 1657493688119
                },
                {
                    "price": 0,
                    "time": 1657580088132
                },
                {
                    "price": 1.0112,
                    "time": 1657666488329
                },
                {
                    "price": 0.9017,
                    "time": 1657752888460
                },
                {
                    "price": 0.636,
                    "time": 1657839288486
                }
            ],
            "opensea_floor_price": 0.619,
            "authFlag": 0
        },
        {
            "nft_platform": "Otherdeed",
            "nft_address": "0x34d85c9cdeb23fa97cb08333b511ac86e1c4e258",
            "floor_price": 2.661,
            "average_price": 5.0461,
            "total_value": 550.0226,
            "count": 109,
            "image": "https://logo.nftscan.com/logo/0x34d85c9cdeb23fa97cb08333b511ac86e1c4e258.png",
            "highest_price": 30,
            "total_supply": 100000,
            "market_cap": 577990,
            "holders": 35025,
            "volume7dList": [
                {
                    "volume": 710.0527,
                    "time": 1657320889633
                },
                {
                    "volume": 668.2843,
                    "time": 1657407289658
                },
                {
                    "volume": 552.8932,
                    "time": 1657493689716
                },
                {
                    "volume": 459.7968,
                    "time": 1657580089841
                },
                {
                    "volume": 693.1521,
                    "time": 1657666489863
                },
                {
                    "volume": 648.8504,
                    "time": 1657752889884
                },
                {
                    "volume": 133.768,
                    "time": 1657839289906
                }
            ],
            "price7dList": [
                {
                    "price": 6.7624,
                    "time": 1657320889633
                },
                {
                    "price": 5.4777,
                    "time": 1657407289658
                },
                {
                    "price": 5.8199,
                    "time": 1657493689716
                },
                {
                    "price": 4.7402,
                    "time": 1657580089841
                },
                {
                    "price": 6.5392,
                    "time": 1657666489863
                },
                {
                    "price": 5.742,
                    "time": 1657752889884
                },
                {
                    "price": 4.3151,
                    "time": 1657839289906
                }
            ],
            "opensea_floor_price": 2.78,
            "authFlag": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

This is an example of what I want to return

[image: Example of table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand, you are not setting the state correctly.

According to the response from the api, It is setting the information in data key.

You set the setData(response.assets). However, it should be setData(response.data)

And the other thing, I noticed the key's you are trying to return is not present in array's of object.

Answer (score 0):

Check your state setting on `getAPI` method.

```
setData(response.assets); // It should be response.data
```

Change it to like below.

```
const getAPI = () => {
  const options = { method: "GET", headers: { Accept: "application/json" } };

  fetch(
    `https://www.nftscan.com/nftscan/getTopTrendingData?range=1d&volumeSort=desc`,
    options
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

and you need to render your variables like this.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>{nft.id} , {nft.floor_price }, {nft.sales} </li>
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Use the properties that you need based on your requirements. I just modified the code and sharing the working sandbox link here.

[image: Edit wizardly-water-er8472]